# Bash/python - remove folder recursively with condition

Tags: python, bash, shell, directory, delete-file

I would like to write a script in bash/python, which is able to delete a folder recursively, that doesn't have `'.txt'` files inside.

For example :

```
| Folder1/          --> keep
|--SubFolderA/      --> keep
|----file.txt

| Folder2/          --> delete

| Folder3/          --> keep
|--subFolderA/      --> keep
|----file.txt

| Folder4/          --> delete
|--SubFolderA/      --> delete
|----SubFolderB/    --> delete
|------file.py

| Folder5/          --> keep
|--SubFolderA/      --> keep, because .txt file is in SubFolderB
|----file.sh
|----SubFolderB/    --> keep
|------file.txt

| Folder6/          --> keep
|--SubFolderA/      --> keep
|----file.txt
|----SubFolderB/    --> delete
|------file.py
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think he wants you to do it for him lol

Comment: I've look in bash vith find + rm function but i'have not succeed

Comment: @user3356301 then post the code you've actually tried, and more detail than "not succeed" (e.g. full error messages or inputs and expected and actual outputs).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely use find. like so:

```
find /path -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I'm not going to write the if statement for you, but that should get you started...Actually whatever:

```
path=the/path/to/the/directory/
myvar=$(find $path -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm -rf {} \;)
if [ -z $myvar ]
then
rmdir $path
else
#don't do anything...keep it
fi
```